# How can I create a small color box using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I have a picture on a html file/site and I want to add the list of available colors for that picture. I want to create very small boxes or dots, a small box for every color.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the list of available colors for that picture"? Do you mean the colors which are actually used in the picture?

Answer (score 116):

With old browsers, you would often use [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), but then you would need a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) so this approach is not used often these days.

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box purple"></div>
<div class="box wine"></div>
```

In modern browsers, the easiest way is with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box purple"></div>
  <div class="box wine"></div>
</div>
```

Or alternatively with `display: inline-block`:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box purple"></div>
<div class="box wine"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a small dots, just use icon from font awesome.

```
fa fa-circle
```