# HTML CSS color within border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a small yellow square of 300x300 pixels let's say with a black border. I use:

```
<style>
body  {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
```

But this gives the whole page yellow and not just the square... How can I fix this? Ty

Comment: because you're styling your whole body. Make a div and style that with above properties. Where is your html?

Comment: You are styling the whole `body` in other word the whole page

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226126/how-can-i-create-a-small-color-box-using-html-and-css/11226586

Comment: The question is relevant. I'm using a third-party library, it has an iframe, that's where the body needs to be fixed. I am unable to add a div.

Answer (score 1):

The `body` tag selects the entire body of the html document. You need to give your box a `id` or `class` and then apply the CSS to that.

For example:

```css
#box  {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've applied to the body, that basically means the whole page.
Insert a DIV on the body.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-class"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div-class{
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only a square of 300x300 you need to make a div for that

```
**HTML:**
<div class='square'></div>


**CSS**

.square  {
background-color: yellow;
border: 1px solid #000000;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
```

Now you are applying your style to the body (whole page). That's why your whole window is yellow instead of 300x300

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the styles to a div and not to the entire body...

```css
.square {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use "body", use "div"

```
div  {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrgqp2ud/